# User can enter up to one room

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making chat. I want user not to enter more than 2 rooms at the same time.

So I made 'enter' model.  This `belongs_to` users and rooms. User `has_one` enter and room `has_many` enters.

In the ApplicationController, there exists `current_user`.

```
def current_user
  return unless session[:user_id]
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

I tried to examine if user has a `enter` or not by following way.

```
def free?
  return unless session[:user_id]
  if current_user.enter.room.count == 1 then
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

This is in the ApplicationController, too.

Next, I wrote `<% if logged_in? && free? %>` in the `views/top/index.html` to display 'join this room' button for only logged in free user.

When I run this, I have following error.

`NoMethodError at/ undefined method 'free?' for #<#<Class:...>...>`

I couldn't solve this on my own... What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create free? method on user object.

```
class User
    def free?
      enter.room.count == 1
    end
end
```

After that inside the view call this, current_user.free?

But will be better if you check if enter object exist with combination of this user and room.